# Why does fetching an ID give me an 404 error

Tags: json, npm, postman, thunderclient

When I'm trying to GET an ID I got an 404 error on any API client. I tried: POSTMAN, INSOMNIA and THUNDER CLIENT.

I did a npm install
`npm install -g json-server`
and
`json-server --watch db.json -p 3200`

This is my db.json file :

```json
{
  "notes": [
    {
      "title": "React - Props",
      "content": "Props are data I can send to a component. You can send any kind of data : Objects, strings, numbers, arrays, jsx...\nYou can never modify a props directly they are read-only. Any time a component props changes the component re-render.\n\nExample : \n\n<Component myProps=\"This is a props\" />",
      "created_at": "23/08/2022",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "React - States",
      "content": "A state is a data managed by a component. Any time a component state changes the component re-render",
      "created_at": "23/08/2022",
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "title": "React - Hooks",
      "content": "Hooks are function that let you use states and other React features. \n\nuseEffect() and useState() are two famous React hooks. ",
      "created_at": "23/08/2022",
      "id": 6
    }


  ]
}
```

Also my GitHub repos: https://github.com/seylioneldev/react-notes-manager/tree/main

http://localhost:3200/notes is working. I can get all the data but http://localhost:3200/notes/2 don't work.

Tried to get an ID but using  http://localhost:3200/notes/2

Comment: Can you use Ping to ping localhost:3200 ?

Comment: sorry i edited my message http://localhost:3200/notes working but not http://localhost:3200/notes/2

Comment: how to ping to ping ?

Comment: Comand Line on PC :  Ping localhost:3200

Comment: ok i did C:\Users\sey_l\Desktop\Coding\repos\react-notes-manager> Ping localhost:3200 and i got :
Ping could not find host localhost:3200. Check the name and try again.

Comment: first time i go this bug just to fetch an id, it works usually on others projects.

Comment: Interesting, if you pinged the ip and port and it could not reach the host .. something is blocking that from making it to your server unrelated to your code, that or the server isn't actually up despite assuming it is.

Comment: I deal with mysql and server complied web code, so I'm not sure how you handle it in this situation, but I know one app i was working on I was unble to connect to the application FROM the server it was hosting it, unless I made a new port just for that, it is some sort of built in protection system, but I wonder if something like that exists in the environment you are dealing with, because you should be able to ping that location unless something is blocking it.  Alas if that is the case I can't tell you how to do it in that enviorment but something to ponder.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. Maybe the problem app coming from this command npm install -g json-server. I will try some test on other project without this to check.

Comment: Good luck and that is the key, keep trying things, you will ge tthere.